# Getting server side value into client side

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, timer

**I want to create a timer for a specific page. The value which should be put into the timer is inside a table. Lets suppose I get the variable from the table using mysql calls and put it inside a php variable.**

**What have I thought**

Using a hidden field, echoing the php variable inside the hidden field's value. Getting the value in javascript.

**The problem**

The javascript code for the timer is executed at the start, and the hidden field normaly is put under the body tag. I am thinking this should rise some problems because the element is not created when the javascript function may check at start.

**Which would be the best way to get this variable inside my javascript code so I can initialize my timer properly.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the JavaScript **[AJAX request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX)** the current state of the timer when it starts, and have PHP generate it on a different page.

By separating the two, you get more flexibility and power. Don't abuse hidden inputs for that.